# Unwanted tables in schema file for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-schema, rake-task

While working on a ruby on rails group project, I found two tables in my schema.rb file that doesn't match with any of the migration history files. Is there a rake command to clean up the schema file of the unintended tables?

I tried commands from `rake -T` but I didn't find one that could remake the schema file.

`rake db:dump` did not change the schema file.

`rake db:schema:dump` also didn't appear to change the schema file.

Comment: try deleting the schema.rb file and running db:schema:dump again

Comment: @eiko But `schema.rb` is a representation of the database that `db:schema:dump` produces, the problem is that there are stray tables in the database.

Comment: @muistooshort I have a distant (maybe false) memory that sometimes schema:dump would do nothing because rake thought schema.rb was already up to date. I figured it would only take a couple seconds to try and was worth a shot. But you're right that it's likely a problem in the db itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the safest way to do this would be like this

```
drop_table :bad_table_names if (table_exists? :bad_table_names)
```

so it should remove it from the schema as well as drop the table checking if it exists. If it does not then it would just pass through safely.

Comment: I hope I am understanding correctly, what you wrote isn't a rake command rather it is just running another migration file to drop the unwanted tables?

Comment: its a migration

Answer (score 0):

`db:schema:dump` creates the schema from what exists in the database. If you drop the tables from the database then rerun it will remove the tables.

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:migrate` should update the schema file with current db state.